# C# WPF MVVM - insert model data into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to post my data from the view to the database but I can't seem to fire the edit function on my view model and I got no clue why it's not working.

My setup is:

- `OverledeneModel` - contains the data
- `OverledeneView` - contains the visible parts
- `OverledeneViewModel` - contains the logic
- `IOverledeneRepository` - contains the commands
- `OverledeneRepository` - contains the actual database queries

When the user is pressing the button "Volgende" the view model is checking if the required fields are not null or whitespace in the `CanExecuteSaveCommand` the next step is `ExecuteSaveCommand` which contains.

```
        if (UitvaartLeider.UitvaartId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            var AddUitvaartleider = overledeneRepository.AddUitvaartleider;

            if (AddUitvaartleider.ToString() != "InsertUitvaartleiderSucces")
                throw new Exception("Uitvaarleider insert has failed");
        }
        else
        {
            var EditUitvaartleider = overledeneRepository.EditUitvaartleider;
            MessageBox.Show(EditUitvaartleider.ToString());

            if (EditUitvaartleider.ToString() != "UpdateUitvaartLeiderSucces")
                throw new Exception("Uitvaartleider update has failed");
        }
```

However the line

```
var EditUitvaartleider = overledeneRepository.EditUitvaartLeider;
```

isn't executed.

```
public class OverledeneRepository : RepositoryBase, IOverledeneRepository
{
    public string AddUitvaartleider(OverledeneUitvaartleiderModel uitvaarLeiderModel)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [OverledeneUitvaartleider] ([UitvaartId], [PersoneelId], [Uitvaartnummer]) VALUES (@uitvaartId', @personeelId', @uitvaartNummer)";

            command.Parameters.Add("@uitvaartId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = uitvaarLeiderModel.UitvaartId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@personeelId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = uitvaarLeiderModel.PersoneelId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uitvaartNummer", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = uitvaarLeiderModel.Uitvaartnummer;
        }

        return "InsertUitvaartleiderSucces"; 
    }
    
    //Editing existing registration
    public string EditUitvaartleider(OverledeneUitvaartleiderModel uitvaartleiderModel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("executed?");
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE [OverledeneUitvaartleider] SET [PersoneelId] = @UitvaartLeiderId, [Uitvaartnummer] = @Uitvaartnummer WHERE [UitvaartId] = @UitvaartGuid";

            command.Parameters.Add("@UitvaartLeiderId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = uitvaartleiderModel.PersoneelId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Uitvaartnummer", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uitvaartleiderModel.Uitvaartnummer;
            command.Parameters.Add("@UitvaartGuid", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = uitvaartleiderModel.UitvaartId;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("done updating");

        return "Done Updating";
    }
}
```

```
public interface IOverledeneRepository
{
    //////////////////
    // CREATE & NEW //
    //////////////////
    string AddUitvaartleider(OverledeneUitvaartleiderModel uitvaarLeiderModel);

    ///////////////////
    // EDIT & UPDATE //
    ///////////////////
    string EditUitvaartleider(OverledeneUitvaartleiderModel uitvaartleiderModel);
}
```

I've read through stackoverflow and google but I can't seem to figure it out why it isn't working.

The data is in the `OverledeneModel`:

```
public class OverledeneUitvaartleiderModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private Guid _uitvaartId;
    private Guid _personeelId;
    private string? _personeelNaam;
    private string? _uitvaartNummer;

    public Guid UitvaartId
    {
        get { return _uitvaartId; }
        set { _uitvaartId = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UitvaartId)); }
    }

    public Guid PersoneelId
    {
        get { return _personeelId; }
        set { _personeelId = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersoneelId)); }
    }

    public string PersoneelNaam
    {
        get { return _personeelNaam; }
        set { _personeelNaam = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersoneelNaam)); }
    }

    public string Uitvaartnummer
    {
        get { return _uitvaartNummer; }
        set { _uitvaartNummer = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Uitvaartnummer)); }
    }

    public string Error => string.Empty;

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (PersoneelId == Guid.Empty ||
                (PersoneelId == null) ||
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Uitvaartnummer)))
            {
                result = "Validatie velden niet correct.";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm completely clueless to why it's not executing.

I hope someone can explain why and help me to make it work.

Comment: `var EditUitvaartleider = overledeneRepository.EditUitvaartleider;` does not call the method - how could it ever, the model argument is missing. check the type of that variable.

Comment: BTW returning `string` as state is very error prone as you already state with your code. If you want to use `string` type then use some const for return and check or use enums

Comment: @SirRufo thanks for pointing me to the obvious, sometimes I feel so stupid, how could i've missed this.

Comment: If you have a solution (we call it answer) then you can also write an answer and also accept it. Remember: This is a Question&Answer site so we are looking for questions and (most important) answers

Comment: Well I guess you did not get the point of this site: It's main purpose is to collect questions&answers which are helpful for future readers. It is not for all of your personal questions, only if they are helpful ... - in this strict terms this question is not very helpful for future readers and it should be closed because it was just a typo (Before you ask: I did **not** downvote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sir Rufo pointed out, I wasn't passing an argument with the call.

```
var EditUitvaartleider = overledeneRepository.EditUitvaartLeider;
```

Should be

```
var EditUitvaartleider = overledeneRepository.EditUitvaartLeider(UitvaartLeider);
```

That did the trick.